# SAP Gateway OData Webservice: Escape statement against XSS

Tags: xss, sapui5

With the intention of this blog [XSS Prevention in UI5](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/03/25/xss-prevention-in-ui5) I escaped the post parameters to avoid xss statements in my database. Next time if I get the information everything works, but it will also escapes non-script strings like this:

before escaping
[image]

after escaping

[image]

The alert command was escaped, but this kind of output is not human readable. How can I handle this? Is it possible to escape *only* javascript?

I could convert it back to readable string. In this case the alert will work again. What is the best practise for this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.sap.escapeHTML("<here><are><some></html></tags>");
```

Output:

```
&lt;here&gt;&lt;are&gt;&lt;some&gt;&lt;&#x2f;html&gt;&lt;&#x2f;tags&gt;
```

HTML will convert `&gt;`, `&lt;` and `&#x2f;` automatically into `</>`, so you prevented XSS.

or just use simple jQuery Style:

```
var someHtmlString = "<script>alert('hi!');</script>";   
$("#mySelector").text(someHtmlString);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a client side escaping. You can always circumvent clientside escaping.